# Open "Terms & Conditions" link in a new tab on checkout page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

The "Terms & Conditions" link shows entire page in a popup window on checkout page of Opencart 2.3.0.2. I want it to be opened in a new tab. I tried but failed to achieve it. I'm usign Porto Theme. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the default template and English, otherwise the instructions may be different, but this should get you started.

In `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl`, you will see a block of text like this:

`<div class="pull-right"><?php echo $text_agree; ?>`

This is what prints the link.  This variable `$text_agree` is set in `catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method.php`.  Here's the logic that does it:

`$data['text_agree'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_agree'), $this->url->link('information/information/agree', 'information_id=' . $this->config->get('config_checkout_id'), true), $information_info['title'], $information_info['title']);`

You want to change this to

`$data['text_agree'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_agree'), $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=5' , true), $information_info['title'], $information_info['title']);`

then last you have the definition of the link.  In `catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/checkout.php` change

`$_['text_agree'] = 'I have read and agree to the <a href="%s" class="agree"><b>%s</b></a>';`

to

`$_['text_agree'] = 'I have read and agree to the <a href="%s" target="_blank"><b>%s</b></a>';`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the detailed explanation. It worked Great. I'm not using the default template but my template is having similar code.

Comment: Glad to help. Please post your template name for the benefit of future readers.